# Густо-рябиновый или густо рябиновый?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Вот текст (Г. Троепольский "Белый Бим Черное Ухо) , который был использован **в качестве диктанта.**

"Все внизу в темных тонах: стволы, прошлогодние темно-коричневые листья, коричнево-серые сухие стебли трав, даже плоды шиповника, **густо-рябиновые** осенью, теперь, выдержав зиму, казались кофейными зернами. 
Ветви слегка шумели от легкого ветра, жидко и голо; они будто ощупывали друг друга, то притрагиваясь концами, то чуть прикасаясь серединой сучьев: жив ли? Верхушки стволов легонько покачивались. Деревья казались живыми даже и безлистные. Все было **таинственно-шуршащим** и **густо-пахучим**: и деревья, и листва под ногами, и шаги Ивана Иваныча, осторожные и тихие".

Выделенные сложные прилагательные здесь написаны **через дефис,** но в авторском тексте они пишутся **раздельно**.

И вопрос: **какое написание вам кажется правильным**?

**Дополнение**

1) Нашла текст в Интернете с дефисным написанием:

Когда они пришли впервые, вечерняя заря только начиналась, а меж деревьев уже сумерки, хотя листья еще и не появились. Все внизу в темных тонах: стволы, прошлогодние **темно-коричневые** листья, коричнево-серые сухие стебли трав, даже плоды шиповника, **густо-рубиновые** осенью, теперь, выдержав зиму, казались кофейными зернами.
Ветки слегка шумели от легкого ветра, жидко и голо они будто ощупывали друг друга, то притрагиваясь концами, то чуть прикасаясь серединой сучьев: жив ли? Верхушки стволов легонько покачивались – деревья казались живыми даже и безлистые. Все было **таинственно-шуршащим и густо-пахучим**: и деревья, и листва под ногами, мягкая, с весенним запахом лесной земли, и шаги Ивана Иваныча, осторожные и тихие. https://www.litmir.co/br/?b=27878&p=4

2) Но объяснить раздельное написание тоже есть желающие:

"Должно быть: **густо рубиновые, таинственно шуршащим, густо пахучим**. Согласно правилу многие сложные прилагательные, употребляемые в качестве научно-технических терминов или книжных выражений, пишутся слитно, в частности сложные прилагательные с первой частью густо-: густокронный, густонаселенный. Однако если в предложении есть пояснительные слова, то образуется свободное сочетание, а не терминологически сложное слово, в данном случае густо рубиновый - это сочетание наречия и прилагательного, поскольку есть пояснительное слово осенью. Также следует различать сложные прилагательные, которые пишутся в одно слово слитно либо через дефис от словосочетаний, состоящих из наречия на -о (-е) и причастия или прилагательного, которые следует писать раздельно. Если это словосочетание, то к наречию всегда можно поставить соответствующий вопрос: все было шуршащим (как?) таинственно; все было пахучим (как?) густо".

Получается, что, возможно, искажается авторский текст, но "мнение" автора не оспаривается, а ошибочное написание объясняется и утверждается (а репетитор (также как и автор произведения) говорит, что должно быть так (=раздельно)).

Comment: У автора "темно коричневые листья" (в текстах, которые я нашел в интернете), что кажется полным безобразием. А почему "даже плоды шиповника, густо рябиновые осенью, теперь, выдержав зиму, казались кофейными зернами" не отделено хотя бы точкой с запятой? Первое восприятие: "Все внизу в темных тонах: стволы, прошлогодние темно-коричневые листья, коричнево-серые сухие стебли трав, даже плоды шиповника" - и вдруг оказывается, что  плоды шиповника относятся к другому предложению.

Comment: Да, точка с запятой не помешала бы. Но всё-таки какое написание правильное и как его объяснить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я, в своём тексте, в случаях сложных прилагательных выбираю дефис или даже слитное написание;

если в приведённых примерах "оправдывать" дефис, то такое написание мы подгоним под

> [**качество с дополнительным оттенком**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/134-def-19-20), например: раскатисто-громкий,
>   горько-соленый;

или сочтём

> **[индивидуально-авторскими образованиями](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xP0Psc8RAFYJ:kasko.ptz.ru/misc/pravila-napisaniya-slozhnih-prilagatelnih.html%20&cd=9&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)**: честно-голубые глаза, выпукло-серые пуговицы, смугло-волосатые руки.

Случайно обнаружила анализ подобных черездефисных написаний у Паустовского:

> [Исследователи его творческого наследия](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/slozhnye-imena-prilagatelnye-v-yazykovom-nasledii-k-g-paustovskogo-osobennosti-slovoobrazovaniya-i-upotrebleniya) единодушны в том, что К.
>   Паустовский — сторонник использования традиционных языковых средств. В
>   этой связи значительный интерес представляет рассмотрение тех
>   лексических единиц, которые не являются достоянием общенародного
>   языка, а представляют собой индивидуально-авторские неологизмы.
>
> Примером могут служить следующие окказионализмы, образованные путем
>   сложения или сложения с одновременной суффиксацией опорной основы:
>
> ***домовито-архитектурный, туманно-синеватый, зернисто-зеленый, парфюмерно-сентиментальный, придирчиво-любопытный,
>   настороженно-любопытный, потрепанно-элегантный, светотканый,
>   бешено-зеленый, полурелигиозно-полуполитический, воздуходувный,
>   атласно-зеленый, туманно-синеватый, обаятельно-добрый,
>   стандартно-примитивный, пугливо-любопытный, добродушно-насмешливый,
>   придирчиво-любопытный, настороженно-любопытный, водянисто-голубой,
>   атласно-зеленый, зернисто-зеленый, дымчато-белый, маслянисто-черный,
>   сумрачно-черный, плакатно-желтый др.***

Из приведённых в подвопросье слов я бы только *густо-пахучим* одефисила,

ещё подумав, соглашусь на *густо-рябиновый* - как оттенок рябинового,

таинственно-шуршащим?.. Это авторская воля, не корректора, не редактора: как он слышит! Слышит раздельное написание - хай маеть наречие и прилагательное.

Comment: А мне авторский неологизм "таинственно-шуршащий" очень нравится: всё было шуршащим и  таинственным, а не шуршало (как?) таинственно. Это художественное письмо, а не школьный синтаксис.

Comment: Так я ж и говорю про него: авторская воля, как писать! В это нельзя вмешиваться! А про раздельное написание у автора было в подвопросье сказано, до "Дополнения"!

Comment: Галина, спасибо Вам за ответ,  я как раз поддерживаю ваше мнение о свободном творчестве автора. Просто хотелось узнать, какой вариант Вам больше нравится.

Comment: Сиби, чукча не читатель, чукча писатель! Так как я на письме абсолютно во власти собственного интуитивного чувствования Слова, я за любым автором оставляю это право. Вон сколько всего неологического у традиционнейшего Паустовского обнаружено.

Answer (score 1):

Наполненность, насыщенность и избыточность, а не оттенки в этих *таинственных* и *густых* шуршаниях, запахах, красках. И, поскольку они не добавляют конкретных характеристик (например: *сине*-зелёный), а только усиливают, не разнообразят и разбивают, а работают на целостность описания, эти наречия не должны быть привязаны дефисом к определениям.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, но мне сложно с ним согласиться. Мне кажется, что наречия как раз мешают целостности восприятия и в какой-то мере более свойственны нехудожественным стилям речи (жизненно необходимый, общественно полезный и т.д.).  А густо-рябиновый - это вообще явный оттенок цвета, слово соответствует классическим правилам дефисного написания, его корректор не должен бы пропускать. И как Вам информация о том, что у автора скорее было именно дефисное написание?

Comment: «Скорее было» буду воспринимать как слух. Насчёт «густо-рябинового» скажу, что такого цвета не может быть по той причине, что нет рябинового. Есть оранжевый.

Comment: И чем это рябиновый хуже малинового или василькового? "Потом за стеклом мелькнул малиновый край одеяла, и внизу глухо стукнуло". [Виктор Пелевин. Желтая стрела (1993)].  "Кашмирские сапфиры ― темно-синего цвета, для цейлонских камней характерен васильковый или серо-синий тон". [А. Е. Ферсман. Воспоминания о камне (1940)]

Comment: У шиповника тоже цвет есть, но автор соотносит его с рябиновым. Почему не наоборот? Не знаю (всё — в руках у автора), но предполагаю, что и тот и другой переменчив, нестоек и век плодов недолог. Недаром краски получают из металлов и камней.

Comment: Название "рябиновый цвет" часто используется в текстах, его нельзя назвать авторским неологизмом, например: "Этот цвет (зеленый) идеален в интерьерах в стиле ретро. Вы можете подобрать ему в пару контрастный рябиновый или фиолетовый, чтобы зеленый заиграл еще ярче".

Comment: Авторский стиль непоследователен: то пользуется основной палитрой, то отходит от неё. Почему не использует вместо зелёного луковый, к примеру? Потому, что прозаично больно.

Comment: Так у автора-то не "рябиновый", а _**рубиновый**_. Или не так?

Comment: Густо-рубиновые осенью, так? Как звёзды на башнях? Не знаю, Sibylla должна определиться.

Comment: Кажется, да, рубиновый, а вот в первом диктанте - рябиновый, вот мы и переключились на него. Ну, заодно и рябиновый обсудили.